# Unable to Enable wifi on HP laptop

Tags: windows-8.1, wifi-configuration

On a Windows 8.1 64 bit laptop that's a HP Pro Book 6560b the wireless network will not enable to allow me to connect to a wireless network. The wifi light stays yellow when I press function key to turn it on\off that does nothing to help fix the problem.

I looked at the bios settings and I do not see much except LAN\WLAN Switching but that did not help either. I checked the HP site for wireless network card drivers and I have the newest installed. I think the light on it needs to be blue to be turned on and I can not figure this out for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Unable to Enable wifi on HP laptop**
>
> The wifi light stays yellow when I press function key to turn it
>   on\off that does nothing

I had this problem a few years back on a similar make and model HP laptop, and I documented the steps I took to resolve it so I'll put the steps I took to resolve below to potentially help you.

1. Go to **HP** website and lookup the model laptop you have and download the latest BIOS firmware update. Install it and reboot the machine to see if that resolves your issue.

   - Here's the **Window 8.1 x64 HP driver download page** for [HP Notebook System BIOS Update](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5045606&swItemId=ob_169818_1&swEnvOid=4158) so you can download from there if you'd like.
2. If you still have trouble then it appears you want to go into the BIOS settings and. . .

   - first select and apply "**Restore Defaults**"
   - second in the "**System Configuration**" section you want to be sure the options *are checked to enable* both "**Wireless Button State**" and "**Embedded WLAN Device**"
   - third (and optional according to my notes) the "**LAN/WLAN Switching**"

Lastly, you will want to reboot your laptop one last time after completing the above steps, and then when it comes back up check to see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: This worked wonderfully by following these steps!!